# ActiveVOS BPEL Process Timeout Exception

Tags: soap, bpel

I would like to have your suggestions on this.
I am new to ActiveVOS BPEL, please don't mind if my question seems dumb to you!

When we pass the data through SOAP UI, in ActiveVOS Designer upon removing the fault handler and change]ing the PDD Option "**Suspend on uncaught Fault**" to "**true**" for the BPEL process, I'm able to suspend and resume the process in the activeVOS Admin console.
Although, whenever I send the data through SOAP UI, it is giving me the time out exception without any response, **but I could see the instance created in the Console**.

When a request is sent through the SOAP UI, if we add FaultHandler to the BPEL process, the process directly ends up with the completed state. The options to resume the suspeneded process are disabled. I**nstead, I would like to resume the suspended process as well as response from the SOAP UI**. Please address this and help me to achieve the intended result.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

the only thing that you can do is to place a scope (BPMN subprocess) and placing all activities from the initial receive (message catch event) to the initial reply (message throw event) in it. Then you can place an catch all fault handler in this scope. This will catch all errors that you want to suspend the process. Place a reply (message throw event) and a suspend after it in the fault handler. The reply will take care that the process caller will get some meaningful response and the ActiveVOS-specific suspend activity will then suspend the process. You can then rewind it or repair it by any means available in the ActiveVOS Console as long as you have a high enough persistence level configured in your PDD/server.

Comment: Thanks Daniel!

I have tried it yesterday. Well, BPEL process is getting suspended without giving me an option to edit the data and rewind back the process for running in ActiveVOS console.

Comment: If you do not have the option to do that your persistence and logging properties are not correct in the PDD. Try setting persistence to Full and logging to Execution and redeploy. Then you can use the Console to rewind the process, change data and skip or execute activities.